# android applications interactions

Tags: android, testing

I have a problem and a don't know how to solve it. I saw some tools for automation testing for android apps, like appium and others. They connect to the android device, emulator, from outside the device and open the application to be tested. I want to know how can i build a native android app that can to the same thing. Open another application and start executing different operations on the UI of that app. For a simple example, let's say i have a social app that i want to test. I want another that runs on the phone that opens my social app and starts running some operations like searching inside the app, clicking on different posts, liking post, s.o. Is there a way to do this? Are there any frameworks or methods for doing this?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two kinds of automation frameworks for Android.

Instrumentation-based:

- [Robotium](https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium)
- [Espresso](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/)

And black-box frameworks for functional testing:

- [Appium](http://appium.io/)
- [Perfecto](https://www.perfectomobile.com/)
- [ATMOSPHERE](http://atmosphereframework.com/)

The instrumentation frameworks work in the following way: As each android application runs in a sandbox and other applications can not change their behavior once they are installed, the instrumentation-based frameworks change the installation package of the application injecting hooks in the method definitions that allow them to interact with the application. This allows bypassing the sandbox in Android systems.

The other three all have `UIAutomator` Android service as basis for the interaction with the application. `UIAutomator` is part of hte Android SDK and allows emulation of real user interactions (e.g. click, scroll etc.), rahter than simulating them on lower, code level.

I believe that any of the five listed frameworks will allow you achieve what you want. I personally recommend black-box testing frameworks, as instrumentation can hide defects. My favorite framework is ATMOSPHERE - free to use, open sourced and although very recent a lot easier to use.

Comment: Thx for your answer. But all of this frameworks connects from outside the device and run the test. I need something that runs on the device and it is able to open other apps for testing running inside the emulator, not outside.

Comment: @user978123 all these frameworks have component running on the device that connects to another component residing on the developer machine. the purpose of the out-of-device component is to visualize and interpret the results. Alternative will be to change any of the open sourced frameworks and have the on-device component write results on the device itself (or communicate them via HTTP), which will allow you to extract the results on a later stage.

Answer (score 1):

You would use an explicit intent to open a separate application.

```
public void openApplication(Context context, String packageName) {
    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        if (i != null) {
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            context.startActivity(i);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to start application");
            return;
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Package name not found");
        return;
    }
}
```

You would then call this method by providing the context and the package name of the application you want to open. For example, to open Instagram:

```
openApplication(this, "com.instagram.android");
```